# Are there secret combos or attacks?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I'm looking for secret attacks like a certain characters with an item or secret combos like the "up,up,down,down,left,right,left,right,b,a" combo (I tried this one and it didn't do anything).

Comment: that's the [Konami Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code) which is a cheat. if it was in Super Smash Brothers i would assume it only associated with Solid Snake being a character from a Konami Game, though i haven't played no. 4 myself thinking on how it would look in the n64 game it wouldn't even be a combo since most of it your just moving the body, not connecting any sort of hit

Comment: is  a combomove-list available in ssb4 like in most Beat'em ups like tekken?

Comment: @Nitro.de No. There are no combomoves like in tekken. SSB completely bases on single attacks which you can chain together however you want. A good example would be with captain falcon: Run -> Downthrow -> Jump -> Up-A -> Jump -> Side A. There is no predefined movelist in SSB. And that's why the game is like 10 times more difficult than tekken or DoA. If you want to look at some decent falcon combos, you can take a look at this video. This guy is pretty good, even though my falcon is much better. ;P https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRz4LuHbI1k

Comment: There's some great answers here, but overall, I highly suggest looking at some SSB techniques.  Due to the nature of the game, Every character has moves that can combo/cancle into each each other.  Likewise, while it's not secret techs, some characters can preform moves like wall jumping/clinging that can confuse an opponent.

Other such techs like fast fall breaking (start into a fast fall, preform an attack to slow down, fast fall again) are high level techs that seperate tournament play from casual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike regular fighting games, the super smash bros series have not any combination input that result in a different attack.

Try as much as you want to make your megaman pulling off a hadouken, it just won't happen.

But if you really want a new kind of attack, some taunt animations can damage your opponents
ie : Luigi's sweeping kick - 1% damage and very slow

Comment: Sweeping kick is a hilarious move for edgeguarding btw, I saw people on tournaments winning with this move, e.G. Boss vs Shofu a few months ago.

Answer (score 7):

As of [update 1.0.8](http://www.ssbwiki.com/List_of_updates_(SSB4-Wii_U)#1.0.8), Ryu, from the Street Fighter series, is available as a paid downloadable character. Uniquely among the characters in the game, he has the non-obvious command inputs you allude to, all of which are variations on [his Special Moves](http://www.smashbros.com/us/characters/ryu.html):

- [Hadoken](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Hadoken): `Neutral special (Special button alone).` Shoots a slow-moving blue energy projectile.

  - [Input Hadoken](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Hadoken#Input_Hadoken): `Quarter-circle forward (down, down-forward, forward + Attack or Special button).` Projectile is slightly larger and 1.25 times stronger.
  - [Shakunetsu Hadoken](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Hadoken#Shakunetsu_Hadoken): `Half-circle forward (back, down-back, down, down-forward, forward + Attack or Special button).` Projectile is red, has a flame effect, and hits multiple times on contact before exploding.
  - When Kirby copies this move, he too gains access to these input variations.
- [Tatsumaki Senpukyaku](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Tatsumaki_Senpukyaku): `Side special (forward or back + Special button).` A spinning kick that slows descent when airborne.

  - [Input Tatsumaki Senpukyaku](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Tatsumaki_Senpukyaku#Input_Tatsumaki_Senpukyaku): `Half-circle backward (forward, down-forward, down, down-back, back + Attack or Special button).` Kick lasts longer, faster, and 1.16 times stronger.
- [Shoryuken](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Shoryuken): `Up special (up + Special button)`. An uppercut.

  - [Input Shoryuken](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Shoryuken#Input_Shoryuken): `"Z" input (forward, down, down-forward + Attack or Special)`. Increases power; Ryu gains invincibility until he starts to fall and receives no landing lag when he touches down.
- [Focus Attack](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Focus_Attack): `Down special (down + Special button)`. Stuns opponents with a charged punch.

  - There are no input variations, but you can cancel the attack by `forward, forward` or `back, back`. If done after hitting the opponent, they'll still be stunned, but you'll end the animation sooner.

If that's not enough, Ryu also has unique move variations (on all of his Attack and Special moves) depending on whether you tap or hold the appropriate button - holding generally makes the move stronger.

Answer (score 5):

All attacks in Super Smash Bros. are performed with a directional input and one button. You can sometimes chain these moves together to form combos, but there are no multi-button input combos like you're imagining.

Most forward smashes (control stick forward + A simultaneously) can be angled up or down by starting the attack by moving the stick forward, but then moving it up or down before the move finishes. This might not be obvious to players at first. Usually the attack is the same, just angled a little bit up or down instead of straight forward.

Little Mac is unique in that his angled forward smashes are actually entirely new attacks with new animations and properties - Standard forward smash is a powerful forward punch, up-angled forward smash is an uppercut with vertical knockback, and down-angled is a low sweep that does high shield damage but low knockback. That's the only case of "secret" attacks I can think of.